# Bootstrap 4 Making row fixed height and connect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently making a messaging system and I'm making the front end with bootstrap, but I have a small problem. I'm trying to make a row which a fixed height. I know I can do this with pixels but then it's not (I don't know how to explain this) fixed. You can see in the picture below the two rows. They're highlighted with the black borders.
[image]

As you can see in the picture the bottom row is fixed in place at the bottom which is good. But the top row needs to be the remaining height and fixed. That way its connected to the bottom part and can't get any more height so, in theory, making the scrollbar activate if the content inside has more height then the rows fixed height. 
I tried doing it with `Height: -webkit-fill-available` but then it fils in the whole card that the row is in. How can I accomplish this without using for instance `min-height: 600px;`

```css
.z-depth-1 {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.txt-bubble {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.txt-bubble-response {
    background-color: #0069D9;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#conversation {
    max-height: 553px;
    min-height: 553px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="card z-depth-1" id="conversation">
      <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row conversationrow">

              <div class="col-md-1">
                  <img src="img/foto.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle" width="52">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-11">
                  <p class="txt-bubble">Maar er zit een klein probleem aan dit systeem</p>
                  <small class="text-muted">2 Dagen geleden</small>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-11">
                  <p class="txt-bubble-response">Ja klopt. Ik moet ervoor zorgen dat de kaart waar deze dingen in zitten, Scrolbaar wordt.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-11">
                  <p class="txt-bubble-response laatste">Zodat de gebruiker niet de hele pagina hoeft te scrollen.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-11">
                  <p class="txt-bubble-response laatste">Maar alleen de box waar de berichten in zitten.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                  <img src="img/foto.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle float-right" width="52" >
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-1">
                  <img src="img/foto.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle" width="52">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-11">
                  <p class="txt-bubble">Hoe ga je dat doen dan? </p>
                  <small class="text-muted">2 Dagen geleden</small>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-11">
                  <p class="txt-bubble-response laatste">Ik heb geen flauw idee, Ik heb het op StackOverflow gevraagt.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                  <img src="img/foto.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle float-right" width="52" >
              </div>

          </div>


          <div class="row" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%;">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <hr>
              </div>
              
              <div class="col-md-10">
                  <form action="">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SearchInbox" aria-describedby="inboxHelp" placeholder="Stuur een bericht">

                      </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right btn-send-msg">Versturen</button>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the liberty to go ahead and re-write your front end code. It can be seen on CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/jaymanpandya/pen/EwLrLR)

The code is as follows:

### HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="z-depth-1" id="conversation">
        <div class="card-body" id="scroll-body">

        <div class="col-md-12 chat-block-row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsBpJyPNKUR0nW9IRoXLp3N7V0-eJJkx_dItFRIheHCYNxHYPi" alt="" class="rounded-circle" width="52">
            </div><!-- col-md-1 ends -->
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <p class="txt-bubble">Maar er zit een klein probleem aan dit systeem</p>
                <small class="text-muted">2 Dagen geleden</small>
            </div><!-- col-md-11 ends -->
        </div><!-- col-md-12 ends -->

        <div class="col-md-12 chat-block-row response">
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <p class="txt-bubble-response">Ja klopt. Ik moet ervoor zorgen dat de kaart waar deze dingen in zitten, Scrolbaar wordt.</p>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <p class="txt-bubble-response laatste">Zodat de gebruiker niet de hele pagina hoeft te scrollen.</p>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <p class="txt-bubble-response laatste">Maar alleen de box waar de berichten in zitten.</p>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <small class="text-muted">2 Dagen geleden</small>
            </div><!-- col-md-11 ends -->
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUESmCuDnAe26tFJDmg9A_b5O0NA1sjtL92t2Mz2IG5Co1XLiq" alt="" class="rounded-circle" width="52">
            </div><!-- col-md-1 ends -->
        </div><!-- col-md-12 ends -->

        <div class="col-md-12 chat-block-row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsBpJyPNKUR0nW9IRoXLp3N7V0-eJJkx_dItFRIheHCYNxHYPi" alt="" class="rounded-circle" width="52">
            </div><!-- col-md-1 ends -->
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <p class="txt-bubble">Hoe ga je dat doen dan?</p>
                <small class="text-muted">2 Dagen geleden</small>
            </div><!-- col-md-11 ends -->
        </div><!-- col-md-12 ends -->

            <div class="col-md-12 chat-block-row response">
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <p class="txt-bubble-response">Ik heb geen flauw idee, Ik heb het op StackOverflow gevraagt.</p>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <small class="text-muted">2 Dagen geleden</small>
                </div><!-- col-md-11 ends -->
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUESmCuDnAe26tFJDmg9A_b5O0NA1sjtL92t2Mz2IG5Co1XLiq" alt="" class="rounded-circle" width="52">
                </div><!-- col-md-1 ends -->
            </div><!-- col-md-12 ends -->

        </div><!-- card-body ends -->

        <div class="col-md-12 form">
            <hr>
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" class="searchField col-md-10" id="SearchInbox" aria-describedby="inboxHelp" placeholder="Stuur een bericht">
                <button type="button" class="col-md-2 btn btn-outline-primary float-right btn-send-msg">Versturen</button>
            </form>
        </div><!-- col-md-12 & form ends -->


    </div><!-- z-depth-1 ends -->
</div><!-- col-md-9 ends -->
```

### CSS

```
.z-depth-1 {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position:relative;
}

.card-body {
    /*display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;*/
    max-height: 300px;
    padding: 2% 0; /*This is added only to add space at top and bottom. Can be ignored. */
overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chat-block-row {
    padding: 1% 0; /*This is added only to add space at top and bottom. Can be ignored. */
}

.txt-bubble {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.txt-bubble-response {
    background-color: #0069D9;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}

#conversation {
    height: 400px;
}

.form {
    position: absolute !important;
    bottom: 2%; /* This value is set to 2% to have some space between the edge of the covering container and the form*/
    left:0;
}

.searchField  {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: .5% 0;
}

.response {
    text-align: right;
}
```

### JS

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("scroll-body");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I absolutely appreciate the effort that you took but unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for. The thing I need is; if the height of the texts row/div exceeds a certain height then the scrollbar will be activated. I've added a couple of new texts to your answer but it just goes through the card instead of stopping. Because with `overflow-y:scroll` it is supposed to stop at that height and activate the scrollbar. I hope this clarifies what my problem is. If not I can make a gif for clarity

Comment: I have updated the [CodePen] (https://codepen.io/jaymanpandya/pen/EwLrLR) . Have a look at it and let me know if it is behaving the way you want it to. If not please make a GIF & post. :)

Comment: That was exactly what I'm looking for, You sir are amazing! One small question on the side though; The person on the left side of the conversation has a `<small>` tag which indicates the time it was posted. But so far I could only get it on the left side. How do I get the person on the right side to have time indicators as well? Thanks :D

Comment: I have edited the code in CodePen and have also edited in the answer to accommodate the time stamp in the right side of the conversation. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: One very last question. Sorry but them I'm done, Is it possible in JS or CSS to start at the bottom? What I mean by that is. If the content is so long that it's scrollable that if I click on it; it starts from the bottom and that you have to scroll up to read past messages? Simply said, The scrollbar needs to start at the bottom instead of the top

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the basics and build on top:

**HTML**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">

    <div class="chat-view col p-0">
      <!-- Chat Messages Here -->
    </div>

    <div class="chat-post">
      <!-- Chat Form Here -->
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.card {
  height: 553px;
}

.card-body {
  height: 100%;
}

.chat-view {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

---

Here's a JsFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/xjx0bdvk/1/